# How to get user info (role) from loopback token from client after login

Tags: vue.js, loopbackjs, loopback

I have a instance of User and instance of Role attached to it. Both are basic models provided from Loopback and they show up in RoleMapping and they work in ACL fine.

So, lets say I logg user in from my Vue client, then I get the response containing the access token in id field so I can make further auth requests, how do I then retrieve basic user info from that access token. Is there a way of parsing it or should I somehow modify the /login remote hook?

Any thoughts?

Comment: the best way will be to modify the login hook as if you include the users as a part of the response you expose some very sensitive data to end user which might not be needed like accestoken ttl etc

Answer (score 4):

> you need to call the login api with "include" option

```
/api/users/login?include=User
```

> in response you will get something like this

```
{
"id": "CZY4lbJbJ2J6DrEIAjYAHfTEZbLMC2tWpyM7sZaKs7rZ1PhIY3mycua0kOHlDXfR",
"ttl": 1209600,
"created": "2018-01-21T17:01:20.183Z",
"userId": "5a3e614339e67f0e580642af",
"user": {
  "createdAt": "2017-12-23T13:59:31.314Z",
  "email": "dummy@dummy.co",
  "id": "5a3e614339e67f0e580642af",
  "name": "dummy",
}
```

you can try it in explorer

Comment: thanks, this solved my problem by defining the realm also!

Comment: Hey I would like to ask one more thing. What would be the best way to restrict user registration? In my app, I have admin role and I would like to accept/decline user registration before it gets written to db. Any thoughts on this? Thanks :D

Comment: This includes user not role.